# Error executing docker-compose: Building webserver unable to prepare context: unable to 'git clone' to temporary context directory: error fetching

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, airflow

I'm following [this](https://github.com/tuanavu/airflow-tutorial) Apache Airflow tutorial and I'm failing to execute

```
docker-compose up -d
```

command.
I get following error:

```
Building webserver
unable to prepare context: unable to 'git clone' to temporary context directory: error fetching: /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: /tmp/_MEItH0v3Q/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4)
: exit status 128
ERROR: Service 'webserver' failed to build
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

I've installed exactly that version of OPEN SSL - OPENSSL_1_1_1 but error remains.
I've also updated git to 2.30.2 because I've read it could fix it but no luck.

Comment: I have this same issue. I don't know what caused it, and the recommended answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have the same issue and the accepted answer not working for me: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @CarMoreno I've removed accepted answer since it's not working obviously. I haven't tested given answer because I've switched on local Airflow installation meanwhile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. Apparently this is a known bug for docker-compose 1.29 and Ubuntu 20 [1]

My `docker-compose` was [installed using curl](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose-on-linux-systems).

What worked for me was removing `docker-compose` and install it using pip instead:

```sh
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
pip3 install docker-compose
```

After that everything worked as expected.

---

1. This bug has been reported several times:

   - https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8170
   - https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8309
   - https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8461
     At the time of this writing (December 2021) things have not yet been resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Also getting this after downloading a fresh `docker-compose` version. I'm also on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, `docker-compose version 1.29.1, build c34c88b2`.

Downgrading to `1.27.4` "resolve" the error…

Isn't it supposed to be statically linked?

Comment: Yup, it worked for me.
I downgraded from `docker-compose version 1.29.2` to `docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192`

My Environment
`Ubuntu 20.04.2`

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered the same problem. I'm only starting with docker and airflow, so I can't really say why this fix works, but it works, so here it is:

Change in `docker-compose.yaml` a tag for `puckel/docker-airflow` from `1.10.1` to `1.10.9`.
Your webserver section in docker-compose.yaml file should start like this:

```yaml
webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
    build:
      context: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow.git#1.10.9
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```