# ERROR: Service 'webserver' failed to build

Tags: git, docker, airflow, archlinux

Working in Arch Linux I am trying to build Apache Airflow following the instructions [here](https://github.com/tuanavu/airflow-tutorial).

```
docker-compose up -d
```

It keeps returning the error

```
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
Building webserver
unable to prepare context: unable to 'git clone' to temporary context directory: error fetching: /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: /tmp/_MEIQm99AZ/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4)
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: /tmp/_MEIQm99AZ/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1)
: exit status 128
```

I have tried following the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579446/error-executing-docker-compose-building-webserver-unable-to-prepare-context-un) without help.

Comment: You could use the official Docker-compose setup instead, check this guide: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

Comment: @NicoE thank you for this. Finally worked. Though I had to change the conditions in the YAML file from `service_completed_successfully` to `service_started` for `docker-compose up airflow-init` : run database migrations and create the first user account: to work. Why is that so?